# não consigo exibir um toast em 2 activitys do mesmo package

Tags: java, android-studio, android-activity, toasts

estou fazendo uma tela de cadastro e login em meu app, na tela de cadastro implementei alguns toasts de tratamentos de exceção, na hora de emular o app os toasts da tela de cadastro exibem normalmente. fiz um processo similar para a tela de login mas a mesma não exibe os avisos. tentei mudar a tela de login de package mas ainda assim não deu certo. o que pode estar acontecendo ?

obs. a tela de cadastro está como **Main41Activity** e a tela de login está como **Main4Activity**

```
package com.example.institutofecomercio.TELA4;
```

public class Main41Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText campoNome, campoEmail, campoSenha;
    private Button botaoCadastrar;
    private FirebaseAuth autenticacao;
    private Usuario usuario;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main41);


    campoNome = findViewById(R.id.editNome);
    campoEmail = findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
    campoSenha = findViewById(R.id.editSenha);
    botaoCadastrar = findViewById(R.id.buttonCadastrar);



    botaoCadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String textoNome = campoNome.getText().toString();
            String textoEmail = campoEmail.getText().toString();
            String textoSenha = campoSenha.getText().toString();


            //Validar se os campos foram preenchidos
            if (!textoNome.isEmpty()) {
                if (!textoEmail.isEmpty()) {
                    if (!textoSenha.isEmpty()) {
                        usuario = new Usuario();
                        usuario.setNome(textoNome);
                        usuario.setEmail(textoEmail);
                        usuario.setSenha(textoSenha);

                        cadastrarUsuario();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Main41Activity.this,
                                "Preencha a senha!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Main41Activity.this,
                            "Preencha o email!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Main41Activity.this,
                        "Preencha a senha!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }
    });


}
public void cadastrarUsuario() {
    autenticacao = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao();
    autenticacao.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            usuario.getEmail(), usuario.getSenha()

    ).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                Toast.makeText(Main41Activity.this,
                        "sucesso ao cadastrar o usuario!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
               String execao = "";
                try {
              throw task.getException();
               } catch ( FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException e) {
                    execao = "Digite uma senha mais consistente!";
                } catch ( FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                         execao = "Por favor, digite um e-mail válido";
                } catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
                   execao = "esta conta já foi cadastrada";
                } catch (Exception e){
                execao = "Erro ao cadastrar usuário" + e.getMessage();
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    Toast.makeText(Main41Activity.this,
                            execao,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }
    });
}}




package com.example.institutofecomercio.TELA4;
```

public class Main4Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText campoEmail, campoSenha;
    private Button botaoEntrar;
    private Usuario usuario;
    private FirebaseAuth autenticacao;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);

    campoEmail = findViewById(R.id.editEmail1);
    campoSenha = findViewById(R.id.editSenha1);
    botaoEntrar = findViewById(R.id.buttonEntrar1);

    botaoEntrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String textoEmail = campoEmail.getText().toString();
            String textoSenha = campoSenha.getText().toString();

            if ( !textoEmail.isEmpty() ){
                if ( !textoSenha.isEmpty() ){

                    usuario = new Usuario();
                    usuario.setEmail( textoEmail );
                    usuario.setSenha( textoSenha );
                    validarLogin();

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(Main4Activity.this,
                            "Preencha a senha!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(Main4Activity.this,
                        "Preencha o email!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });

}

public void validarLogin() {

    autenticacao = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao();
    autenticacao.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            usuario.getEmail(),
            usuario.getSenha()
    ).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {


                Toast.makeText(Main4Activity.this,
                        "Sucesso ao fazer login",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Main4Activity.this,
                        "Erro ao fazer login",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                String excecao = "";
                try {
                    throw task.getException();
                } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException e) {
                    excecao = "Usuário não está cadastrado.";
                } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                    excecao = "E-mail e senha não correspondem a um usuário cadastrado";
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    excecao = "Erro ao cadastrar usuário: " + e.getMessage();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Toast.makeText(Main4Activity.this,
                        excecao,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}}
```

Answer (score -1):

tente usar

```
getApplicationContext()
```

no lugar de

```
Main4Activity.this
```